# Restrict SharePoint O365 Group Permissions to Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions

I have created a Modern SharePoint Collaboration/Team Site with myself as Owner and X as member. So now I have myself as "Owner" and X as "Member" in the GROUP MEMBERSHIP. X is able to participate in Teams discussions, create Planner items, etc. However, I do not want X to be able to edit certain pages on SharePoint site. X should be able to view these pages only. My question is - Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

As a another user is a **Member** of your site he/she is having **Edit** permissions on the **Site Pages** library (these permissions are inherited from site level).

In order to restrict users from editing the pages, you have to options:

1. Prevent users from editing all pages
2. Prevent users from editing specific pages.

In both cases you need to use **Stop Inheriting Permissions** option.

Check below detailed article to achieve the same:

[How to prevent team site members from editing SharePoint pages](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-prevent-team-site-members-from-editing-sharepoint-pages/) .

**Additional references**:

1. [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels).
2. [How to create and edit permission levels?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels)

**Update**:

**Restricting editing specific pages in modern experience**:

1. Navigate to the **Site Pages** library.
2. Then Click the check box next to the page you want to restrict from editing, then click on little `i` in a circle, then **Manage access**.

   [image]
3. Then select the **drop-down** next to **Members** group and then choose **Can view**.

   [image]

This will prevent all group members from editing that particular page.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this only works for a classic SharePoint site. This does not work for Modern SharePoint sites where by default group membership is added and all group members will continue to have access even when the "Members" group does not contain any users.

Comment: I have tried it myself and it works fine for modern experience also. let me add detailed explanation in my answer.

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if this works for you or if you face any issues.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thank you for the detailed explanation. This will only modify the site permission, not the O365 group permission. It seems there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think your site is a team site which is connected to Office 365 group.By default we could not change the group member permissions through UI interface.

As a workaround, you could use powershell command to ser GroupMember permissions to read.

```
connect-sposervice https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael -identity "MichaelGroup Members" -PermissionLevelsToRemove "Edit" -PermissionLevelsToAdd "Read"
```

Then give X access to edit certain page.

As site owner, run the follwing pnp powershell:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael"
$GroupName="Michael Member"

#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Set Group Permissions: Remove "Edit" and Add "Contribute"
Set-PnPGroup -Identity $GroupName -AddRole "Read" -RemoveRole "Edit"
```

Comment: I know that this can be done from the tenant admin end through PowerShell. I was hoping that there would be someway for a non-admin (site owner) user to do it as well. Thank you.

Comment: As site owner, you could run pnp powershell to achieve this. I have updated my answer.